# Access alias properties in Ebean when loading initial test data in Play

Tags: yaml, playframework-2.1, ebean

I'm loading initial test data for my models in Play 2.1.

I would like to access the String property "question" of Question Model.
Here is my initial-data.yml file:

```
- &q1 !!models.Question
    id: 001
    question: Sample question?

- &mem1 !!models.Member
    id: 001
    memberName: Test

!!models.SecurityQuestion
    member: *mem1
    question:  *q1.question
    answer: sample answer
```

But all I get is the following error:

```
Test models.ModelsTest.fullTest failed: while scanning an alias; expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found .
```

How do I access the properties of an alias?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
    questions: 

            - !!models.Question
                id: 001
                question: Sample question?


    members: 

            - !!models.Member
                id: 001
                memberName: Test


    security:

            !!models.SecurityQuestion
                member:   !!models.Member
                                id: 001
                question: !!models.Question
                                id: 001
                answer: sample answer
```